# gzread() fails when continue reads in seperate php requests

Tags: php, gzip, fwrite, fread

I have **gz** compressed file and uncompressing it to normal file so I use `fwrite()`. It works fine when do uncompress in a single PHP request.

Because of large compressed files, I do mind in PHP timeouts, I uncompress the file until 30 seconds and stop the process and store the current `offset` of **gz** file using `gztell()` then continue it form the next PHP request where I left.

I do `gzseek()` with current offset and continue the uncompression but `gzread()` continuously gives empty string

```
function gz_uncompress_file($source, $offset = 0){

    $dest =  str_replace('.gz', '', $source);

    $fp_in = gzopen($source, 'rb');

    if (empty($fp_in)) {
        return 'Cannot open gzfile to uncompress sql';
    }

    $fp_out = fopen($dest, 'ab');

    if (empty($fp_out)) {
        return 'Cannot open temp file to uncompress sql';
    }

    gzseek($fp_in, $offset);

    $break = false;

    while (!gzeof($fp_in)){

        $chunk_data = gzread($fp_in, 1024 * 512);

        if (empty($chunk_data)) {
            return 'empty string so stop the process';
        }

        fwrite($fp_out, $chunk_data);

        //Clearning to save memory
        unset($chunk_data);

        if(!is_time_out()){
            continue;
        }

        $break = true;
        $offset = gztell($fp_in);
        break;
    }

    fclose($fp_out);
    gzclose($fp_in);

    if ($break) {
        //Saving offset
        $this->set_option('sql_gz_uncompression_offset', $offset);

        return 'continue_from_call';
    }

    echo "Un compression done";
}
```

Comment: May I ask what gzseek return?

Comment: retuerns`0` always and PHP doc says `Upon success, returns 0` http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzseek.php

Comment: when `gzread` returns an empty string, I tried to `gztell` and it gives exactly offset where I left. so I think seeking works correctly

Comment: Have you considered the following note: "If the file is opened for writing, only forward seeks are supported; gzseek() then compresses a sequence of zeroes up to the new starting position." ?

Comment: So it means it cannot be seek in the middle ?